# Computer freezing frequently at random intervals

Tags: windows, windows-10, freeze

I'm using windows 10 in my hp Probook 4540s.

*My Computer freezes frequently at random intervals of 2 or 3 seconds*. If I turn on the PC from first window itself it is behaving like this.

I'm facing this issue for the first time. Why it is happening like this?
What I need to do to solve this issue.

Comment: Try updating drivers. it may also be worth checking to see if the BIOS has the hard disk configured for IDE ("Compatibility") or AHCI mode. It may also be worth uninstalling (from `Device Manager`) your hard disk controller drivers (this will force a restart) and let Windows re-install them... next it'll be worth doing the likes of a disk check, RAM test and checking to make sure you haven't got a heat or GPU problem...

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you monitor your CPU usage and memory via Performance Monitor.

Check the event in the Event Viewer if there is any related event.

And run command chkdsk / f / r

Answer (score 0):

You should check following things:

- Installed drivers.
- Compatibility between hardware and software.
- Whether configuration setup is done properly or not.

These are some of the things which you need to check on immediate basis.